# how to determine the address pointed to by a pointer? (theory)

Tags: pointers, memory-address, information-theory

I have this question:

> let a double pointer "ptr" point to this address: "0xb786ff12".
> if I write the following line: ptr + 4. say the final address to which ptr points to.

my attempt:
because ptr is a 32 bit double precision pointer, it has 8 bytes; therefore, I have to count using hexadecimal, as follows:
(starting from 12)

13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 1a (first set of 8 bytes)

1b, 1c, 1d, 1e, 1f, 21, 22, 23 (second set of 8 bytes)

24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 2a, 2b, (third set of 8 bytes)

2c, 2d, 2e, 2f, 31, 32, 33, 34  (fourth set of 8 bytes)

but it's not correct, because the final result must be 0xb786ff32, 32, not 34.

I know it could be obvious, but I personally find it a little tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counting is wrong! See below:

13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 1a (first set of 8 bytes)

1b, 1c, 1d, 1e, 1f, **20**, 21, 22 (second set of 8 bytes)

23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 2a, (third set of 8 bytes)

2b, 2c, 2d, 2e, 2f, **30**, 31, 32 (fourth set of 8 bytes)

#f is followed by (#+1)0, not by (#+1)1, as in your sequence (1f was followed by 21, and 2f was followed by 31)